# Need help optimizing this tSQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm definitely not a DBA and unfortunately we don't have a DBA to consult within at our company. I was wondering if someone could give me a recommendation on how to improve this query, either by changing the query itself or adding indexes to the database.

Looking at the execution plan of the query it seems like the outer joins are killing the query.  This query only returns 350k results, but it takes almost 30 seconds to complete. I don't know much about DB's, but I don't think this is good? Perhaps I'm wrong?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

As a side note this is obviously being create by an ORM and not me directly. We are using Linq-to-SQL.

```
SELECT 
    [t12].[value] AS [DiscoveryEnabled], 
    [t12].[value2] AS [isConnected], 
    [t12].[Interface], 
    [t12].[Description] AS [InterfaceDescription], 
    [t12].[value3] AS [Duplex], 
    [t12].[value4] AS [IsEnabled], 
    [t12].[value5] AS [Host], 
    [t12].[value6] AS [HostIP], 
    [t12].[value7] AS [MAC], 
    [t12].[value8] AS [MACadded], 
    [t12].[value9] AS [PortFast], 
    [t12].[value10] AS [PortSecurity], 
    [t12].[value11] AS [ShortHost], 
    [t12].[value12] AS [SNMPlink], 
    [t12].[value13] AS [Speed], 
    [t12].[value14] AS [InterfaceStatus], 
    [t12].[InterfaceType], 
    [t12].[value15] AS [IsUserPort], 
    [t12].[value16] AS [VLAN], 
    [t12].[value17] AS [Code], 
    [t12].[Description2] AS [Description], 
    [t12].[Host] AS [DeviceName], 
    [t12].[NET_OUID], 
    [t12].[DisplayName] AS [Net_OU], 
    [t12].[Enclave]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [t1].[DiscoveryEnabled] AS [value], 
        [t1].[IsConnected] AS [value2], 
        [t0].[Interface], 
        [t0].[Description], 
        [t2].[Duplex] AS [value3], 
        [t0].[IsEnabled] AS [value4], 
        [t3].[Host] AS [value5], 
        [t6].[Address] AS [value6], 
        [t3].[MAC] AS [value7], 
        [t3].[MACadded] AS [value8], 
        [t2].[PortFast] AS [value9], 
        [t2].[PortSecurity] AS [value10], 
        [t4].[Host] AS [value11], 
        [t0].[SNMPlink] AS [value12], 
        [t2].[Speed] AS [value13], 
        [t2].[InterfaceStatus] AS [value14], 
        [t8].[InterfaceType], 
        [t0].[IsUserPort] AS [value15], 
        [t2].[VLAN] AS [value16], 
        [t9].[Code] AS [value17], 
        [t9].[Description] AS [Description2], 
        [t7].[Host], [t7].[NET_OUID], 
        [t10].[DisplayName], 
        [t11].[Enclave], 
        [t7].[Decommissioned]
    FROM [dbo].[IDB_Interface] AS [t0]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IDB_InterfaceLayer2] AS [t1] ON [t0].[IDB_Interface_ID] = [t1].[IDB_Interface_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IDB_LANinterface] AS [t2] ON [t1].[IDB_InterfaceLayer2_ID] = [t2].[IDB_InterfaceLayer2_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IDB_Host] AS [t3] ON [t2].[IDB_LANinterface_ID] = [t3].[IDB_LANinterface_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IDB_Infrastructure] AS [t4] ON [t0].[IDB_Interface_ID] = [t4].[IDB_Interface_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IDB_AddressMapIPv4] AS [t5] ON [t3].[IDB_AddressMapIPv4_ID] = ([t5].[IDB_AddressMapIPv4_ID])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[IDB_AddressIPv4] AS [t6] ON [t5].[IDB_AddressIPv4_ID] = [t6].[IDB_AddressIPv4_ID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ART_Asset] AS [t7] ON [t7].[ART_Asset_ID] = [t0].[ART_Asset_ID]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[NSD_InterfaceType] AS [t8] ON [t8].[NSD_InterfaceTypeID] = [t0].[NSD_InterfaceTypeID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[NSD_InterfaceCode] AS [t9] ON [t9].[NSD_InterfaceCodeID] = [t0].[NSD_InterfaceCodeID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[NET_OU] AS [t10] ON [t10].[NET_OUID] = [t7].[NET_OUID]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[NET_Enclave] AS [t11] ON [t11].[NET_EnclaveID] = [t10].[NET_EnclaveID]
    ) AS [t12]
WHERE ([t12].[Enclave] = 'USMC') AND (NOT ([t12].[Decommissioned] = 1))
```

LINQ-TO-SQL Query:

```
return from t in db.IDB_Interfaces
             join v in db.IDB_InterfaceLayer3s on t.IDB_Interface_ID equals v.IDB_Interface_ID
             join u in db.ART_Assets on t.ART_Asset_ID equals u.ART_Asset_ID
             join c in db.NET_OUs on u.NET_OUID equals c.NET_OUID
             join w in
               (from d in db.IDB_InterfaceIPv4s
                select new { d.IDB_InterfaceIPv4_ID, d.IDB_InterfaceLayer3_ID, d.IDB_AddressMapIPv4_ID, d.IDB_AddressMapIPv4.IDB_AddressIPv4.Address })
             on v.IDB_InterfaceLayer3_ID equals w.IDB_InterfaceLayer3_ID
             join h in db.NET_Enclaves on c.NET_EnclaveID equals h.NET_EnclaveID into enclaveLeftJoin
             from i in enclaveLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join m in
               (from z in db.IDB_StandbyIPv4s
                select new
                {
                  z.IDB_InterfaceIPv4_ID,
                  z.IDB_AddressMapIPv4_ID,
                  z.IDB_AddressMapIPv4.IDB_AddressIPv4.Address,
                  z.Preempt,
                  z.Priority
                })
             on w.IDB_InterfaceIPv4_ID equals m.IDB_InterfaceIPv4_ID into standbyLeftJoin
             from k in standbyLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where t.ART_Asset.Decommissioned == false
             select new NetIDBGridDataResults
             {
               DeviceName = u.Host,
               Host = u.Host,
               Interface = t.Interface,
               IPAddress = w.Address,
               ACLIn = v.InboundACL,
               ACLOut = v.OutboundACL,
               VirtualAddress = k.Address,
               VirtualPriority = k.Priority,
               VirtualPreempt = k.Preempt,
               InterfaceDescription = t.Description,
               Enclave = i.Enclave
             };
```

Comment: You need to tell us about the table structure and what indexes are already in place.

Comment: When you say 30 seconds to return the data, where is the data going? If you're running it in SSMS then it could easily take 30 seconds just for the UI to display the data not to mention the time to get it over the network if you're not actually on the server.

Comment: Please post the execution plan **in text format**. Run `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON GO SELECT …`

Comment: Also, I'm not clear on why you are using a subquery at all.

Comment: First thing to check: do you have good indices - especially on those foreign key columns (`IDB_Interface_ID` and so on) in your tables? And could you show us the LINQ query that leads to this SQL query??

Comment: @Tom H.: as he mentions - it's Linq-to-SQL that's creating this query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule (and this is very general), you want an index on:

- `JOIN` fields (both sides)
- Common `WHERE` filter fields
- Possibly fields you aggregate

For this query, start with checking your `JOIN` criteria.  Any one of those missing will force a table scan which is a big hit.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at the execution plan of the query it seems like the outer joins are killing the query. 
>   This query only returns 350k results, but it takes almost 30 seconds to complete. I don't know 
>   much about DB's, but I don't think this is good? Perhaps I'm wrong?

A man has got to do waht a mana has got to do.

The joins may kill you, but when you need them YOU NEED THEM. Some tasks take long.

- Make sure you ahve all indices you need.
- Make sure your sql server is not a sad joke hardware wise.
  All you can do.

I woudl bet someone has no clue about SQL and needs to be enlighted to the power of indices.

Comment: There are PK's/FK's to every table.  However, I do have no clue about indices.  Sort of why I'm asking here.

Comment: Well, then RTFM. CREATE INDEX is your friend. YOU kill the database with inefficient table scans. And no, sorry, Stackoverflow doesn ot stop you from reading an intro into databases article.